# Spoon with Marmalade in Space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vibrations, adhesion

I sit in a space shuttle in zero gravity condition.
I have a spoon in one hand and the jar of marmalade in the other.
I take marmalade with spoon.

If I shake it very hard, will the marmalade detach from the spoon?
Yes, why, no, why not?

Comment: It isn't very different from shaking a spoon on Earth. If you shake hard enough, you can make marmalade fly off up, down, or sideways.